# Asp.Net Core 2.1 WebApi returns 400 when sending request from Angular 6 WebApp to get access_token

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular6, openiddict

I've got an application that is represented by asp.net core 2.1 web api on the server side and angular 6 on the client side. OpenIddict is used on the server side to support token authentication. The main problem is that when a request is sent from angular app to the server to generate or refresh access_token for a client, the server responds with the 400 (Bad Request), though when it is send from Postman everything works just fine. The Cors policy is added to allow corss-origin requests as client and server sides are placed on different ports so simple requests from angular to the server passes fine.

Here is the Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        hostingEnvironment = env;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    private IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContextPool<HospitalContext>(options => 
         {
             options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
             options.UseOpenIddict();
         });

        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowLocalhost4200", builder => 
        { 
            builder
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
            .WithHeaders("Authorization", "Content-type")
            .WithMethods("Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete");
        }));

        services.AddCustomIdentity();
        services.AddCustomOpenIddict(hostingEnvironment);

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors("AllowLocalhost4200");
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();
        app.InitilizeDb();
    }
}
```

and AddCustomOpenIddict method which is in ConfigureServices method if someone needs to see the configuration:

```
 public static IServiceCollection AddCustomOpenIddict(this IServiceCollection services, 
                                                              IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        services.AddOpenIddict(options =>
        {
            options.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<HospitalContext>();
            options.AddMvcBinders();
            options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token");
            options.EnableAuthorizationEndpoint("/connect/authorize");
            options.AllowRefreshTokenFlow()
                   .AllowImplicitFlow();

            options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
            options.SetIdentityTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
            options.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60));

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
            }

            options.AddEphemeralSigningKey();
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultForbidScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddOAuthValidation();

        return services;
    }
```

The Angular method that sends a request is:

```
public authorize(model: ILoginModel): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:58300/connect/token`,
                          this.authService.authFormBody(model),
                          {headers: this.authService.authHeaders()});
}
```

with this.authService.authFormBody and this.authService.authHeaders:

```
authHeaders(): Headers {
    const headers = new Headers(
    {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
    return headers;
}

authFormBody(model: ILoginModel): string {
    let body = '';
    body += 'grant_type=password&';
    body += 'username=' + model.email + '&';
    body += 'password=' + model.password + '&';
    body += 'scope=OpenId profile OfflineAccess Roles';
    return body;
}
```

I'm actually new to token based authetication, so maybe there is a problem in configurations or something. Would appreciate any offers to solve a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an error, it was just really that I removed AddPasswordFlow from my configs and left AllowRefreshTokenFlow() and AllowImplicitFlow() and was sending grant_type=password to the server that was not cofigured to accept such a grant, it was my mistake there. It is supposed to be:

```
services.AddOpenIddict(options =>
    {
        //some configs

        options.AllowPasswordFlow()
               .AllowRefreshTokenFlow()
               .AllowImplicitFlow();

        //some configs
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For the begining, try allowing all headers:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1#set-the-allowed-request-headers

Later, to be precise, look at all headers your angular app is sending and allow all of them in your cors policy. To start with, allow `application-x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: First, I tried allowing all headers, but that didn't change anything. Second, in that case angular sends a request with 'Content-Type' header, that's all...and it is allowed in Cors Policy and concerning 'application-x-www-form-urlencoded' it is the type of the body of the request that is specified in Conten-type header, not a header as I understand it. So, unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: your angular app runs on `http://localhost:4200`? not https, not some other port?

Comment: that looks pretty usual. only thing i see is: try using uppercase for verbs or allowallmethod()

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo in your authFormBody method:

```
body += 'grant_type=password$';
```

This should be written as:

```
body += 'grant_type=password&';
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it was just the typo here while pasting...even if it was it, it would at least reach the method on the server '/connect/token' and it would sent me my own defined Bad Request with a description.